# Use a knockout component without the view model .JS file?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs, knockout-3.0, knockout-3.2

I'm trying to create a knockout component and load its template from a file like so:

```
function ordersViewModel(){
   //whatever
}

function equipmentViewModel(){
   //whatever
}

ko.components.register('compact-view', {
    viewModel: ordersViewModel,
    template: {require: '../views/orders/compactTable.html'},
    synchronous: true
});

var MasterModel = function(){
    this.orders = new ordersViewModel(),
    this.equipment = new equipmentViewModel();
};

var mm = new MasterModel();
```

And I'm getting the following error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   https://localhost/views/orders/compactTable.html.js

It seems it is looking for the .js as detailed [in the docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html):

> For this to work, the files `files/component-like-widget.js` and `files/component-like-widget.html` need to exist.

Isn't there a way to use a component without having to separate the viewmodel in another file?

I'm using a MasterModel to be able to call other viewmodel functions from any other viewmodel, and probably separating the `ordersViewModel` in another file will make things more difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definetely possible to do it, you can separately specify the viewModel and the template for a component.

In your case the problem is that you are missing `text!` before the template path and so RequireJs tries to load it as a javascript resource.

Also, you need to include the RequireJs text plugin: https://github.com/requirejs/text

Comment: `template: {require: 'text!../views/orders/compactTable.html'},` is not working either. It tries to get `GET https://localhost/text.js `. `Uncaught Error: Script error for: text`

Comment: Which module loader are you using? I am assuming you use require.js

Comment: I am using require.js yeah. Just added the `require.js` in my page header before the main javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Component with no viewmodel
namespace Components {

export namespace NoViewModelComponent{

    export const componentName = 'no-viewmodel-component';

   //No Viewmodel as is taken care of elsewhere
    (function register() {
        ko.components.register(componentName, {
            template: {
             //using require
              require: 'text!' + BASE_URL + 'Views/Components/NoViewModelView.html'
             //OR direct html
             //'<div > {{My Var}}</div>'
            }

        });
    })();
  }    
}
```